# You have called ADD_LIBRARY for library pugixml without any source files

Tags: cmake

I am working on quickrank: https://github.com/hpclab/quickrank. when I compile it I get error

```
 cmake .. -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPLIER=/usr/bin/g++ -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
You have called ADD_LIBRARY for library pugixml without any source files. This typically indicates a problem with your CMakeLists.txt file
-- Configuring done
CMake Error: Cannot determine link language for target "pugixml".
CMake Error: CMake can not determine linker language for target: pugixml
CMake Error: CMake can not determine linker language for target: pugixml
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/students/s4438236/quickrank/build_
s4438236@moss:~/quickrank/build_$ make
make[2]: *** No rule to make target `CMakeFiles/pugixml.dir/build'.  Stop.
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/pugixml.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I do find source file under the `lib\pugixml` folder, how can I fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

When you call the `add_library` CMake command, you must provide source files for this target. If we examine the top-level `CMakeLists.txt` file, we see where the error is occurring:

```
# external libraries
file(GLOB_RECURSE pugixml_sources ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/pugixml/src/*.cpp)
add_library(pugixml STATIC ${pugixml_sources})
```

The CMake error suggests that the `pugixml_sources` variable is empty, which hints that the `/lib/pubixml` may have also been empty. If you initially didn't run the `git clone` command with `--recursive`, you would not have gotten the pugixml submodule.

Seeing as you said the pugixml sources are now there, I would suggest deleting your CMake cache and the CMake build folder. Running CMake again from scratch will likely allow it to see the pugixml source files.